# Emacs: paste from previous copies

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, if I have made copy-and-paste of three different texts, what shortcut keys can I use to paste the first text that I copied? Ctrl+Y will  paste the last(third) copy. Thanks!

Comment: This is basic stuff. Have you even gone through the quick tutorial on emacs?

Comment: M-x browse-kill-ring  is another good  option: Look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing  Specifically at browse-kill-ring.el.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `M-y` (`yank-pop`) immediately after `C-y` (`yank`) to cycle through your kill ring.

So, to paste the first text out of three do `C-y M-y M-y`.

See [earlier kills](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Earlier-Kills.html) in the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/) for details on how this works.

Comment: so in MELPA there's the same stuff with a nice popup: `popup-kill-ring`. To install: `package-install RET popup-kill-ring RET`.